# Testing fetch() method inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdom, enzyme

I have an App component that is responsible for rendering child input components, it is also responsible for handling fetch requests to the Twitch API via a method called `channelSearch`. I have tried to adhere to suggested best practices outlined [here](http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/) for working with ajax/fetch with React.

The method is passed down through props and called via a callback.

Note the fetch method is actually isomorphic-fetch.

```
channelSearch (searchReq, baseUrl="https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/") {
  fetch(baseUrl + searchReq)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({newChannel:json});
  })
  .then( () => {
    if (!("error" in this.state.newChannel) && this.channelChecker(this.state.newChannel._id, this.state.channelList) ) {
      this.setState(
        {channelList: this.state.channelList.concat([this.state.newChannel])}
      );
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return error;
  });
}
```

I am currently trying to write a test for the `channelSearch` method. I am currently using enzyme and jsdom to `mount` the entire `<App>` component in a DOM. Find the child node with the callback, simulate a click (which should fire the callback) and check to see if the state of the component has been changed. However, this does not seem to work.

I have also tried calling the method directly, however, I run into problems with `this.state` being undefined.

```
test('channel search method should change newChannel state', t => {
  const wrapper = mount(React.createElement(App));

  wrapper.find('input').get(0).value = "test";
  console.log(wrapper.find('input').get(0).value);
  wrapper.find('input').simulate("change");

  wrapper.find('button').simulate("click");

  console.log(wrapper.state(["newChannel"]));


});
```

I am really lost, I am not sure if the method itself is poorly written or I am not using the correct tools for the job. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**Update #1:**

I included nock as recommended in comments, test now looks like this:

```
test('channel search method should change newChannel state', t => {
  // Test object setup

  var twitch = nock('https://api.twitch.tv')
                .log(console.log)
                .get('/kraken/channels/test')
                .reply(200, {
                  _id: '001',
                  name: 'test',
                  game: 'testGame'
                });

  function checker() {
    if(twitch.isDone()) {
      console.log("Done!");
      console.log(wrapper.state(["newChannel"]));
    }
    else {
      checker();
    }
  }

  const wrapper = mount(React.createElement(App));
  wrapper.find('input').get(0).value = "test";
  wrapper.find('input').simulate("change");
  wrapper.find('button').simulate("click");

  checker();
});
```

This still does not seem to change the state of the component.

Comment: Please include your tests, as they're clearly part of the question :)

Comment: @markthethomas Added, thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1):

fetch is asynchronous but you're testing synchronously, you need to either mock fetch with a synchronous mock or make the test asynchronous.

[nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) may work for you here.

Comment: I have updates my test to try and attempt to mock fetch with nock as suggested, however, I am still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a sample of your test using [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/).

I agree with Tom that you're testing synchronously. It would of course be helpful to show off your actual component code (all of the relevant portions, like what calls `channelSearch`, or at the least describe it by saying e.g. "`channelSearch` is called by `componentDidMount()`". You said:

> I run into problems with this.state being undefined.

This is because [`this.setState()` is asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html). This is for performance reasons, so that React can batch changes.

**I suspect you'll need to change your code that is currently:**

```
.then(json => {
    this.setState({newChannel:json});
})
```

**to:**

```
.then(json => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    this.setState({newChannel:json}, resolve);
  })
})
```

Note that your `checker()` method won't work. It's looping, but `twitch.isDone()` will never be true because it never has a chance to run. Javascript is single threaded, so your checker code will run continuously, not allowing anything else in between.

If you set up the plnkr, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor out the `fetch` code from the component then pass it it to the component as a callback function in the properties.

```js
export class Channel extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.searchFunction().then(data => this.setState(data));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state}</div>;
  }
}
```

Uage:

```js
function channelSearch(name) {
  return fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/channels?query=${name}`);
}

<Channel searchFunction={channelSearch} />
```

Now you can test the API functionality independently of the component.